# Searching multiple columns (as.factor) within Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

I am trying to make an R shiny app where the user can filter across multiple columns and these columns are factor, so they can select a specific category in each column. I notice that the filter is based on all values of each columns. I would like to apply a filter in one column and when filtering another one I would like to display only categories that exist for that filter, not all of them.

From the following example, if I filter "4.3" in the first column (Sepal.Length) it will show only one row, however when I try to apply an additional filter on any other column all variable will be displayed, but in reality I would expect that it should display only one single option.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput('tbl')))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT(
      iris %>% mutate_all(as.factor),
      options = list(
        scrollX = TRUE,
        dom = 't',
        lengthChange = FALSE,
        initComplete = JS(
          "function(settings, json) {",
          "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#222d32', 'color': '#fff'});",
          "}")
      ),
      rownames = FALSE,
      filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE)
    )
  }
)
```

Does anyone knows how to do it?

This is the column filter behavior I would like to accomplish:

[Column Filtering using JavaScript](http://live.datatables.net/xehimatu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Thank you.